# Why don't tooltips work inside the carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

As i said, the two of them don't get along together too well. I use Bootstrap 3 (the tooltips) and Cycle2 as the carousel. I really have no idea why they wouldn't work and some insight on this would be greatly appreciated. The javascript is called throught html data attributes as you can see here

```
       <div class="part-1 content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row feed cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-carousel-fluid="true" data-cycle-fx="carousel" data-cycle-timeout="2000">
                    <img src="../images/sc/part-1-alt.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">

                    <img src="../images/sc/part-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">

                    <img src="../images/sc/part-3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">

                    <img src="../images/sc/part-4.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">

                    <img src="../images/sc/part-5.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">

                    <img src="../images/sc/part-6-alt.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the little javascript concerning the the items with tooltips

...

```
$(".part-1 img").tooltip({
    'placement': 'top'
});

$(".part-2.item").tooltip({
    'placement': 'top'
});
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't working because the carousel is using overflow, and the tooltips exceeded its margins.

Comment: how did you fix this issue?

Comment: how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

carousel-inner sets overflow to hidden. You can disable it, however your content (content inside de inner div) needs to use fixed width

Add this to your CSS header

```
carousel-inner {
   overflow: visible;
}
```